# Spacing text field and center swift

Tags: swift, uikit

i want to make the text in center and using spacing

but

[image]

i used

```
textfield.defaultTextAttributes.updateValue(32, forKey: NSAttributedString.Key.kern)
textfield.center = containerView.center
```

and also align center in xib
but the text doesn't become center

is there any other solution?

Comment: ```textfield.textAlignment = .center``` ?

Comment: @uditha i already tried but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolve by making the text alignment of textField as center.

You can do this in UIKIT or programmatically also

**UiKit**:

[image]

**Programmatically**:

```
txtField.textAlignment = .center
```

Comment: i already do it and nothing change

Comment: oh, then this might be an issue with 32-point space after character that is causing this issue.
textfield.defaultTextAttributes.updateValue(32, forKey: NSAttributedString.Key.kern)

Answer (score 0):

When working with text attributes then use:

```
    let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraph.alignment = .center
    
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle:paragraph]
    
    let textfield = UITextField()
    textfield.defaultTextAttributes = attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the kern property every time a character is entered, you need to make a calculation for it. Otherwise, the space between characters will work independently of the center property.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tfff.textAlignment = .center
    tfff.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange), for: .editingChanged) 

}
@objc func textDidChange(){
    guard let count = tfff.text?.count else {
        return
    }
    let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraph.alignment = .center
 
    if count != 0 {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: tfff.text!)
        attributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.kern : 32], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: count - 1))
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraph, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: count - 1))
        tfff.attributedText = attributedString
    }
   
}
```

[image]

[image]